# app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication and UserInfo

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, identityserver3, openid-connect

For my WebAPI, I'm using:
    public void ConfigureAuth( IAppBuilder app )
    {

```
app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication( new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
{
    Authority = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[ "ida:Authority" ],
    RequiredScopes = new[ ]
    {
        "XXXXAPI"
    }
} );
```

}

I authenticate okay, but I need to get my roles and other information supplied by the UserInfo endpoint.

Does UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication do this automatically or is there an event like OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications.AuthroizationCodeReceived that I should be using to set the ClaimsIdentity?

Comment: If you "authenticate okay", you'll have a ClaimsPrincipal with the claims provided by the access token. Either include what you need in the access tokens, or make a seperate call to fetch what you need. I prefer the first approach (less chatty).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication does set the roles and scopes automatically.

For some unkown reason, I only returned data from the GetProfileDataAsync of the UserService only when the caller was UserInfoEndpoint. Once I got rid of this piece of code, all the roles were automatically populated.

Answer (score 0):

You must use OAuth2+JWT and some custom configuration to save user roles and other claims in access token.

1. Add these values in Web.config

   ```
   <appSettings>
      <add key="as:AudienceId" value="414e1927a3884f68abc79f7283837fd1" />
      <add key="as:AudienceSecret" value="qMCdFDQuF23RV1Y-1Gq9L3cF3VmuFwVbam4fMTdAfpo" />
   </appSettings>
   ```
2. Write a CustomJwtFormat class

   ```
   using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
   using Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataHandler.Encoder;
   using System;
   using System.Configuration;
   using System.IdentityModel.Tokens;
   using Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Tokens;
   public class CustomJwtFormat : ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>
   {

   private readonly string _issuer = string.Empty;

   public CustomJwtFormat(string issuer)
   {
       _issuer = issuer;
   }

   public string Protect(AuthenticationTicket data)
   {
       if (data == null)
       {
           throw new ArgumentNullException("data");
       }

       string audienceId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["as:AudienceId"];

       string symmetricKeyAsBase64 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["as:AudienceSecret"];

       var keyByteArray = TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode(symmetricKeyAsBase64);

       var signingKey = new HmacSigningCredentials(keyByteArray);

       var issued = data.Properties.IssuedUtc;

       var expires = data.Properties.ExpiresUtc;

       var token = new JwtSecurityToken(_issuer, audienceId, data.Identity.Claims, issued.Value.UtcDateTime, expires.Value.UtcDateTime, signingKey);

       var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

       var jwt = handler.WriteToken(token);

       return jwt;
   }
   }
   ```
3. Create a custom authenticationProvider

   ```
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Security.Claims;
   using System.Threading.Tasks;
   using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
   using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth;
   public class ApplicationOAuthProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
   {
   public override Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
   {
       context.Validated();
       return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
   }
   public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
   {
       context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });

       using (AuthRepository _repo = new AuthRepository())
       {
           User user = await _repo.FindUser(context.UserName, context.Password);

           if (user == null)
           {
               context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
               return;
           }
       }

       var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
       identity.AddClaim(new Claim("unique_name", context.UserName));
       identity.AddClaim(new Claim("role", "user"));

       context.Validated(identity);
   }
   }
   ```
4. Configure Your Custom Setting

   ```
       private static void ConfigureOAuthTokenGeneration(IAppBuilder app)
   {

       OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
       {
           //For Dev enviroment only (on production should be AllowInsecureHttp = false)
           AllowInsecureHttp = true,
           TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/oauth/token"),
           AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
           Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(),
           AccessTokenFormat = new CustomJwtFormat("http://localhost/")
       };

       // OAuth 2.0 Bearer Access Token Generation
       app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
   }
   private static void ConfigureOAuthTokenConsumption(IAppBuilder app)
   {

       var issuer = "http://localhost/";
       string audienceId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["as:AudienceId"];
       byte[] audienceSecret = TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["as:AudienceSecret"]);

       // Api controllers with an [Authorize] attribute will be validated with JWT
       app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
           new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
           {
               AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
               AllowedAudiences = new[] { audienceId },
               IssuerSecurityTokenProviders = new IIssuerSecurityTokenProvider[]
               {
                   new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityTokenProvider(issuer, audienceSecret)
               }
           });
   }
   public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app(
   {
               app.UseAutofacMvc();
       ConfigureOAuthTokenGeneration(app);
       ConfigureOAuthTokenConsumption(app);
       //other codes
   }
   ```
5. If you want to get userInfo from access token, do it as follows:

   ```
       public static string GetUserNameFromOAuth(HttpRequestMessage Request)
       {
       if (Request.Headers.Contains("Authorization"))
       {
           var authHeader = Request.Headers.GetValues("Authorization");
           var authEncoded = authHeader.FirstOrDefault();
           var authList = authEncoded.Split(' ');
           var payload = authList[1];

           var symmetricKeyAsBase64 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["as:AudienceSecret"];
           var keyByteArray = TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode(symmetricKeyAsBase64);

           var signingKey = new HmacSigningCredentials(keyByteArray);
           string token = JWT.JsonWebToken.Decode(payload, keyByteArray);
           var jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(token);
           var userName = jsonObject.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Key == "unique_name").Value;
           return userName;
       }
       return "";
       }
   ```
6. Test in postman:

[image]